# Angular SSR: Show spinner during the loading of component

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I know to show an animation during the loading for a standard angular build with `npm run build` by placing the picture in the `<app-root></app-root>` tags of the index.html file of project.

But with the Server Side Rendering the spinner isn't shown.

I work on the Angular 9 version.

This is the code I used :

**index.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My webApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<style type="text/css">
    body,
    html {
    height: 100%;
    }

    .app-loading {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    }

    .app-loading .spinner {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
    transform-origin: center center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    }

    .app-loading .spinner .path {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    stroke: #22387B;
    }

    @keyframes rotate {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    }

    @keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }

    50% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -35px;
    }

    100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -124px;
    }
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<app-root>
    <div class="app-loading">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <svg class="spinner" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
        <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
    </svg>
    </div>
</app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe i need to modify the `app.server.module.ts` ..

I havn't found explanation on this subject.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just displayed too quickly?

Comment: yes, when i put the browser network to low connection (2g or 3g), i do not see the spinner, and when i test in dev (with ng serve) it runs correctly

Comment: Maybe deactivate js completely and that way you'll have time to debug why it does not show

Comment: Thx for your help, I' ll do that but I thought that the code between <app-root> tags was'nt detected in SSR build

Comment: HI @narcositi.I have the same problem.  How did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Hi @user9714967, yesterday i finally find a workaround of the problem, i show it on my github's post [here](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/1598) :)

Comment: Thank you @narcosito. I moved the logic to the application component.  Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped you :)